# How to assign group after the ldap parameter?

Tags: python, django, ldap

I would like to assign to group after specific ldap parameter. 
In Django I have other groups then in ldap.

I do something in signals.py, but i want do do the same effect in settings.py, because when I create a new groups i want change something in settings.py

I do this in signals.py ant it works

```
global group_name

if (gidNumber =='201'):
    goup_name = 'a '
elif (gidNumber == '202'):
      user.is_staff = True
      group_name = 'b'
else:
      group_name = 'c'

if(user.groups.filter(name=group_name).exists()!= True ):
      group = Group.objects.get(name=group_name)
      user.groups.add(gruop)
```

but i would ilke do this like smoething like this what i try do this in my settings.py

```
 AUTH_LDAP_USER_FLAGS_BY_GROUP = {
"groups.filter(name='a')": 
"gidNumber=201,uid=%(user)s,ou=People,dc=yy,dc=xx ",
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest answer is to do own dictionary in settings.py

```
LDAP_DICTIONARY = {
    '201':'a',
    '202':'b',
    '203':'c'
    }

AUTH_LDAP_USER_ATTR_MAP = {
    'first_name' : 'gecos',
    'last_name' : 'gidNumber',
     }
```

and in signals.py assign property, but I have only first_name and last_name paremeters, so I gidNumber assign to last_name and clean this paremeter

```
gidNumber = user.last_name    
user.last_name=' '
group_name =LDAP_DICTIONARY[gidNumber]
group = Group.objects.get(name=group_name)
user.groups.add(group)
```